# New Team Project doesn't appear in Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have just created a new Team Project, added items to it, mapped to a local folder and performed a Get Latest, so I am quite confident the project is created and working, yet it doesn't appear in Team Explorer.  To access the project, I need to open Source Control Explorer for a sibling project, and then in the Folders pane, under tfsserver\DefaultCollection, I can see and work with my project.  What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you add a project to TFS it doesn't necessarily show up automatically on the team explorer.  Click the button at the top of Team Explorer that says **Connect to Team Project** and check the box next to your new team project.  That will make it show up in the explorer.

Comment: Kind of unintuitive, no?  Especially since I created it from Team Explorer.

Comment: @ProfK A bit unintuitive.  I know that the TFS team often responds here, maybe they're listening.